# I am unable to create a folder in external sd card in android

Tags: android, storage, external

I have tried this code but it always creates a folder in the phone's internal memory.

```
  String externalDataPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/yourFolder";
    File f = new File(externalDataPath);
    try {
          if (!f.exists()) {
               f.mkdir();
                }
          externalDataPath = externalDataPath + "/" + filename;
          f = new File(externalDataPath);
    
          if (!f.exists())
               f.createNewFile();
    
         externalDataPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Also, I have added **EXTERNAL_WRITE PERMISSION** in Manifest file..

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What version of Android are you targeting. Also have you read: [The Storage Situation: External Storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) and [The Storage Situation: Removable Storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/11/storage-situation-removable-storage.html)

Comment: Have you observed the `catch-block` to see if an `exception` happens?

Comment: If f.mkdir() returns false you should stop. Now you blindly continue.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Android 10, getExternalFilesDir() worked for me, but i am facing issues in saving video into that directory.

Answer (score 1):

A path to your app specific folder on a removable micro sd card can be obtained by using the second item returned by

```
getExternalFilesDirs()
```